# isElementPresent with custom error message strings for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I've recently installed Selenium Webdriver in visual studio and I'm trying to create a function to check isElementPresent with a custom error message included as a parameter based on what is proposed here:

[isElementPresent in selenium 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922930/iselementpresent-in-selenium-2-0)

Currently my script look like

```
private bool isElementPresent(By by, string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by); ;
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to not mix validations in your functions. Use NUnit `Assert`s to validate a `boolean` return.

Your code doesn't actually use the method proposed in the link you referenced. It should look like

```
private bool isElementPresent(By locator)
{
    return Driver.FindElements(locator).Any();
}
```

and be called like

```
Assert.IsTrue(isElementPresent(By.Id("login")), "Verify login button is present");
```

---

NOTE: You may need to add a Linq reference, `using System.Linq;`, in order to use `.Any()`.

Comment: -'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' coud be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)- 

Any doesn't seems to react correctly for some reasons and I'm not sure of why.

Comment: I don't know if you are using Visual Studio but if you hover over `Any()` (it should have a red squiggle), click "Show potential fixes", and then add `using System.Linq;`. The reference you are missing is Linq.

Comment: If this (or any) answer is useful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please accept it as the answer so that it doesn't get left as unanswered.